# nodejs why is variable persisting on page reloads?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following express route:

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router() ;

let a = 0;

route.get('/', (req,res)=> {
            a++;

                res.send(`hello api we are here! ${a}`)

            })


module.exports = route;
```

When i log on to my localhost I get the message : hello api we are here! 1

then when i refresh: hello api we are here! 2

Every time i hit refresh the value of a increments. I always thought that when my browser connects to the server the entire server is reloaded and run from top. What am i missing?

Comment: No the server isn't reloaded... Just no. That's what you were missing.

Comment: you are probably right that i need to do but more reading on the topic, however my confusion arises from the fact that if this was a PHP program the variable would not persist.

Comment: @aryan that's because they're 2 completely different architectures, you're most likely referring to the fact PHP page code is executed as the page loads, Node doesn't work like this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your variable `a` has a scope outside of the route.get. That `a` will increment and store for as long as your express server process is running.

Comment: If people feel the need to downvote me, that's fine if there's a good reason. I think it'd just be useful to the community if you included why so we could all learn.